# open graph api call not recognizing meta tags in redirecting php page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website url `http://website/og.php?params`. This page generates the self-hosting open graph object properties. Internally, the file name is converted to a `OgController.php` and a function in the class is invoked. When I directly create a `og.php` and generate the og meta tags, it works fine. When I redirect to a class function and generate the meta tags, it throws a `(#3502) Object at URL http://website/og.php?params has og:type of 'website'.`. I've run it through facebook's debugger tool. It shows the same thing. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?